# Synchronized collection of variables

Tags: java, synchronization

I want to have synchronized collection (list or set) that will be thread-safe. My collection will contain objects of Variable class, which has fileds like name, value etc. Now lets say two threads want to modify  objects from that list (add new or remove existing ones). Whats the best solution to do it? I found smth like this on stackoverflow.

```
List<Variable> varList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Variable>());

void processList(List<Variable> varList, String name)
{
    synchronized(varList) {
        varList.stream().filter(o -> o.getName().equals(name)).findFirst().ifPresent(o -> o.setValue(100));
    // or
    varList.remove(0);
    // or
    varList.add(new Variable());
    }
}
```

Will it work without any problems? Or are there better solutions?

Comment: If the threads modify the `Variable` objects within the list then the `Variable` class  must be thread safe, not the list.

Comment: That works, the list will be thread safe.

Comment: If you Variable.class is mutable, then you have shared state on this objects that can lead to another "race condition".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution depends on the use case. If you need an ordered randomacces Collection, than there are 3 options.

**1)** The one you described(The [Synchronized List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List))). It will perform as fast as the underlaying Collection type, with the drawBack that the whole Collection will be locked on Thread acces.

Besides the Iterator implementation is not Threadsafe by default, and therefore needs extra threadSafty measures. (An itetator is often used in the `forEach, clear` and other default (java 8) implementations).

**2)** The [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html). This is the only ThreadSafe (including Iterator with snapshot feature) randomAcces List there is in the JDK.

The drawback is that it copies the data when adding/removing data. This might not be a problem for smaller collections, though the base rule is, that its the best solution when there are considerably more 'read' actions than 'write' actions.

**3)** The [Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html). This is a bit slower on the 'read' actions compaired to the CopyOnWriteList, though its 'write' mechanism doesnt require making a copy of the backing data.

A drawback on this one is that the Iterator is not ThreadSafe as well. The difference with a Synchronized list is, that it will perform better than a SynchronizedList when there are considerably more Threads accesing the Collections.

**Sumarry:**

[Synchronized List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List))

- Fast performance with low number of accesing Threads.
- Iterator is not Thread safe

[CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

- Fast performance on 'read' actions
- Copies the backing data on 'write' actions (might be a problem with larger Collections)
- Iterator is Thread safe (using snapshot feature)

[Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)

- Faster performance (compaired to Synchronized List) with large number of accesing Threads.
- Iterator is not Thread safe

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case performace is not so important, so i will  prolly stay with the List. But it seems i have some more problems: 1. I want to change/modify objects inside that list (change their fields, not only remove/add new elements). According to the other comments under my question i need some extra protection? How exactly can i do it?
2. You said that iterator operations arent thread safe for List. So finding object by using stream() and filter() methods isnt a good idea?
3. Do i actually need synchronized list or should i just put "normal" list in synchronized block ?

Comment: 1) synchronization of a `Variable` needs to be handles inside the Object itself. There is no way to do that with a List implementation. So please fix that problem first 2) when using an iterator, the easiest way is to use a synchronized block using the list as lock object . (E.g. `synchronized(varList) { /* do stuff */}`). 3) if you make sure to use a synchronized block everytime you acces the list, it (and the previous part) wont be a problem. Though if performance is not a problem, use a instead `CopyOnWriteArrayList` as it is totally ThreadSafe (excluding the Objects itself of course!)

Comment: Thanks once more for reply. Now it's way more clear for me. But got one more question. If objects that i want to modify are always taken from the same list, do i really need another protection for single Variable instance? Because to get object a thread needs to pass synchronized (varList) statement which wont be possible if another thread is working on the list. So i assume that extra synchronization mechanism is only needed if i would want to access those objects outside of the list, or am i wrong?

Comment: Its kinda true, though if you store a `Variable` instance locally for example (e.g. `Variable var = varList.get(index)`), after your get call returns, other Threads are able to acces the List. Meaning they have acces to the same `Variable` instance eventhough you are not finnished with it yet. (Right now I mentoining a case where you store a `Variable` instance, though when calling inline (e.g. `varList.get(index).doSomething()`) the same problem may occur. When the `get()` method returns the concurrency protection stops, making it vunorable for a big mess.)

Comment: Hmm. So you're saying if i do `  varList.stream().filter(o -> o.getName().equals(name)).findFirst().ifPresent(o -> o.setValue(100));`  inside synchronized(varList) block without any protection for a single `Variable` instance concurrency problems may occure? I thought when one thread is inside synchronized block, the other ones cant enter it as long as the 1st block doesnt release it, or it only protects from making operations on that one object?

Comment: If you do that inside a Synchronized block with the `varList` as lock. than there are no problems. Though if you plan on performing a lot of operations based on one object acces only (the `varList`), you could also choose to use a `(Reentrant)Lock` object instead of synchronized blocks. (E.g. `lock.lock(); try{ //perform stuff } finally { lock.unlock(); }` ). This free's you from a specific List implementation, or even a field reference, as the same lock can be used in multiple places, for multiple actions.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it much more simple. You just need to do all the modifications on the list inside a synchronized block, using the same list object as the lock.

For example, let's suppose you have the list

```
List<Variable> varList;
```

already filled with Variable objects. Now, everytime you want to access or modify this List in your code, you must wrap the piece of code with a synchronized block locking on varList, as follows:

```
    synchronized(varList) {
        // here you access, add, delete, or modify the List
        // for example:
        if(varList.get(1) == 3) {
            varList.remove(1);
            varList.add(new Variable());
        }
    }
```

For this, you must make sure that the two threads are working with the **same** varList, this is, varList is a shared variable for both threads (such as a field, or a static variable). You could also use any other new object as a lock, but always making sure it is a common object for both threads (not two variables with the same name referring to different objects in memory).
But I prefer using the list itself as the lock so it makes the code clearer for me, I know inside that block I am modifying that list.